# Only SPN credential auth scheme is supported for non windows agent

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a linux agent where I want to run a PowerShell script with an azcli command, using Azure Resource Manager service connection.

This is the task I am using :

```
      - task: AzurePowerShell@5
        displayName: 'Add webapp OutboundIPs into SA FW'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }} 
          ScriptType: 'FilePath'
          ScriptPath: '$(path)/update-SA-firewall.ps1'
          ScriptArguments: '-webappOutboundIPs "$(webappOutboundIPs)" -SAName $(SAName)  -RG ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}'
          azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

And this is the script:

```
Param(
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $webappOutboundIPs,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SAName,
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $RG
)

# get the Array of IPs from the given string 
$IPs = $webappOutboundIPs.Split(",")

# Add these IPs into the SA Firewall
 foreach ($ip in $IPs) {
     az storage account network-rule add -g $RG --account-name $SAName --ip-address $ip | out-null
 }
```

The error I get is :

> Line |  106 |      throw ("Only SPN credential auth scheme is
> supported for non wind …
> |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> | **Only SPN credential auth scheme is supported for non windows
> | agent.**
>
> ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Am I missing something here :/ ?

Comment: Looks like a long-standing bug, [does this help](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13372#issuecomment-1000318511)?

Comment: There s no solution there, I think it's a limitation for linux agents. We need to have an SPN to be able to run that script  :/